# Can you call getInstrumentation() from a test class in a referenced Android library?

Tags: android, instrumentation

I am working on implementing automated unit tests for our application. Want i need to do is be able to choose from a list of test cases and execute said test. My initial idea was to create (1) a standalone application that references a (2) testing library (android project with a bunch of unit tests) that would invoke the activities in our (3) application. So our application of course works fine and I don't want to make any changes there if possible. The standalone application would server as an interface to us developers for executing the tests. I want to be able to add more and more tests to the library. The issue I am having at this point is what follows.

In the library project I have a basic LoginTest activity.

```
public class LoginTest extends InstrumentationTestCase
{

  ... other class code


  @Override
  protected void setUp()
  {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation());
  }


}
```

My issue is the `getInstrumentation()` call always returns null. In my library manifest I have

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.matrix.edc.client.android" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the robotium jar installed. The Solo class belongs to the robotium library.

If you have that installed and I've insulted your intelligence try changing your class declaration to

```
 public class LoginTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<YourMainActivity>
```

and change

```
 solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation, getActivity());
```

in `setUp()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure, to call super.setUp() before any attempt of getting the instrumentation. I have not tested every subclass, but for ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2:

```
@Override
protected void setUp()
{
  getInstrumentation(); // returns null
  super.setUp()
  getInstrumentation(); // returns valid instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

trying injecting the instrumentation in your setup, like so

```
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}
```